# Error while creating table in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create a table in android using SQLite but an error has occurred "No such column". I have checked everything is correct, please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks

Code for creating table is:

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Employee.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
public static final String TABLE_EMPLOYEE="Employee";
public static final String COLUMN_ID="Empid";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME="Empname";
public static final  String COLUMN_SALARY="Empsalary";
public static final String createReq="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + COLUMN_SALARY + " NUMERIC" + ")";

public dbhelper(Context context)
{   
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
      Log.e("dbhelper constructor: ", "dbhelper const called..");
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
     Log.e("onCreate method of dbhelper: ", "onCreate method of dbhelper method called..");
    db.execSQL(createReq);
}
```

When i printed the column names of table in logcat, it displays 
col: Empid
Col: EmpnameTEXTEmpsalaryNUMERIC

Comment: put your logcat here..

Comment: Where has the error occured? Put logcat error trace

Comment: try to remove your database from data directory and one more time run your program.

Comment: have you tried inserting values to the tables?

Comment: Please show us your logcat info. In the meanwhile try putting semicolon at the end of your sql statement.

Comment: Logcat:-06-10 09:03:48.027:     E/col:(1814): Column Name:Empid
06-10 09:03:48.037: E/col:(1814): Column Name:EmpnameTEXTEmpsalaryNUMERIC
06-10 09:03:48.048: E/SQLiteLog(1814): (1) table Employee has no column named Empname
06-10 09:03:48.077: E/SQLiteDatabase(1814): Error inserting Empname=Payal Empsalary=12.0
06-10 09:03:48.077: E/SQLiteDatabase(1814): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Employee has no column named Empname (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Employee(Empname,Empsalary) VALUES (?,?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the spaces over here:

Try below code and let me know:

```
public static final String createReq = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_SALARY + " NUMERIC " + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

My original answer is wrong when stating that the `onCreate` method is called every time the `SQLiteOpenHelper` (`dbhelper` in this case) is created. According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) it's only called when the database is created (thanks, @KumarBibek, for bringing this to my attention). This also means that my answer is pretty much useless, as of the reported issue at least. I still choose to keep it alive, partly as a shameful reminder of my hasty mistake :-) but also as it (according to me) has some other useful side notes for any future readers.

**ORIGIN**

Regardless of your current issue, I think you'll meet other problems as well if you try to create your table in the `onCreate` method. Unless you somehow delete your table (in the corresponding `onDestroy` or something) then you'll try to execute a `CREATE TABLE...` query on a table that already exists for every time the `dbhelper` class is "created" by the platform. Your current problem might actually even be because of that (even if I find it a bit unlikely, due to the stated error message).

There is a `onUpgrade` and `onDowngrade` method in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` (which I assume you're extending) where the `onUpgrade` method would be a much more suitable place to create your table, but again: you'll need to delete it before or only execute the create statement for the first version (add an if-check on the `newVersion` method parameter). Alternatively you could [add a `IF NOT EXISTS` escape sequence](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), so that your create statement would look something like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee...`.

If you create an in-memory database this is not an issue (but then your [database file name would begin with a colon](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), like ":Employee.db"). Be aware, though, that all your data will get deleted as soon as your in-memory database is released.

Yet another tip: You can actually test your SQL syntax in an online SQL syntax validator (one example is presented [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14491/online-sql-statement-checker), make sure you choose the correct SQL engine, "SQLite", in the toolbar). These kind of tools will validate your *SQL syntax*. They can, however, not validate the *logical* validity (i.e. errors due to misuse of the Android life cycle).

One other side-note is that class names should, as of unwritten old-school java standard, begin with upper-case letters. Hence, your `dbhelper` class (and thereby also your constructor) should actually read `Dbhelper` or even nicer `DbHelper`

Comment: onCreate is the correct place to create your tables. onUpgrade, as the name suggests, is a place where you do your migrations when the version changes.

Comment: @KumarBibek: Yes, and when you create your database for the first time it will upgrade from nothing to what-ever-version you give it. You should avoid executing lengthy operations in `onCreate` and since you're accessing a file on the filesystem (yes, SQLite databases are file-databases) you are very much executing a "lengthy operation", hence, you should avoid doing it in `onCreate`. The documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) suggests that both methods are fine to use though...

Comment: Going by the same logic, you should also not execute lengthy operations in your onUpgrade method as well. I agree, that if you create your tables in onUpgrade, it would work, but that, according to the docs is not the right place to create your tables. And of course, I know they are file-databases :)

Comment: @KumarBibek: You're right in one point, though. The `onCreate` doesn't seem to be called each time the SQLiteOpenHelper is created, but only when the database is created for the first time. Will change my answer accordingly.